# Filtering map key values by string and return matches - Clojure

Tags: filter, collections, clojure

how can I filter a map by string and return the matches(I need to filter in keys and values at the same time.) key-value pairs as a string. I know it looks like a weird question, it is just about learning Clojure.

Before of everything, thank you for separating your time.

```
;my input map ===>

{1 {:id 1c :race "human" :gender "male"}
 2 {:id 1a :race "cat" :gender "cfemale"}}
```

```
;my filter string
"c"
```

```
;my expected output for "c" ===>

[["id" "1c"] ["race" "human"] ["race" "cat"]["gender" "cfemale"]]
```

```
;my filter string
"r"
```

```
;my expected output for "r" ===>

[["race" "human"] ["race" "cat"]["gender" "cfemale"]["gender" "male"]]
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: to be honest, I know how to filter by just values, so I tried but couldn't write something valuable or even close to working.

Comment: This is an odd input. But given the input you want, the first thing would be to convert your input to a vector of key/value pairs of strings. `(into [] (for [m (vals input-map) [k v] m] [(name k) v]))`

Comment: And then I should try to filter in vectors right?

Comment: yeah, create a function that filters a pair [a b] the way you want, and filter the result of above by your function. `clojure.string/includes?` should work, or use a regex

Answer (score 0):

```
(def my-vec (into [] (for [m (vals my-map) [k v] m] [(name k) v])))


(defn filter-vector-func [coll ?s]
(reduce
  (fn [x y]
    (let [[first second :as all] y]
      (if (str/includes? (str/lower-case all) (str/lower-case ?s))
        (conj x all)
        x)))
  []
  coll))
```

This is working as I want. It is possible to write it with postwalk?